# Fetching a range of rows in Oracle

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to fetch a range of rows in Oracle, but I am only able to fetch from the first row to a row number N.

I cannot do it in case i want to fetch a range in-between the table such as row no. 2 to 5

Lets consider EMP table below that is seen in the sample user SCOTT

[image: Entire Table]

Case 1: Fetch a range of rows from 1 to 5, I get the following

```
select EMPNO, ENAME from (select EMPNO,ENAME from EMP ORDER BY EMPNO)  WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

[image: First 5 Rows]

Case 2: Now lets try and fetch 3 rows between 2 and 5.

```
select EMPNO, ENAME from (select EMPNO,ENAME from EMP ORDER BY EMPNO)  WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```

[image]

This gives me an empty Resultset. Why is that? What do I need to change so that I can get a range of rows from somewhere in between the table?

Comment: As above, as addition you can read [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RANK` function to find the rank of each `empno` and then filter out the records from 2 to 5.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT empno, ename, RANK () OVER (ORDER BY empno) RNK FROM emp)
 WHERE RNK BETWEEN 2 AND 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * FROM (SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMPNO ) AS ROWID, 
   ENAME
 FROM EMP ) EMP where ROWID between 2 and 5
```